# Why the Crate is getting open/close none stop when getting close to it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want that when the player is getting close to the crate it will open once then when the player is getting away from it over 1.5f distance close the crate once then if getting close again open once.

but when the player is getting close to it now it's getting open/close very fast none stop.
if the player is getting far from it it will close once but the problem is when getting close to it.

The script, maybe something is wrong with the logic I did for open and close ?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class UnlockCrate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject carte;
    public Animation anim;

    private bool playAnimOnce = false;

    private void Update()
    {
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(carte.transform.position, transform.position);
        if(distance < 1.5f && playAnimOnce == false)
        {
            anim.Play("Crate_Open");

            playAnimOnce = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if(playAnimOnce == true)
            {
                anim.Play("Crate_Close");

                playAnimOnce = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code appears to read like this (strangely named "crate is open" variable aside):

- If the player is less than (1.5 units) and the crate is not open

  - Open the crate
- Otherwise

  - If the crate is open

    - Close the crate

So it opens when you approach, then the next time through this code it closes it regardless of where you are, even within the 'open' range.

Try this instead:

```
if (distance < 1.5f)
{
    if (!playAnimOnce)
    {
        anim.Play("Crate_Open");
        playAnimOnce = true;
    }
}
else if (playAnimOnce)
{
    anim.Play("Crate_Close");
    playAnimOnce = false;
}
```

Now it will only open the crate if you are in range and it is closed, and will only close it if you are out of range.